# Finding words of the same length

Tags: python, list

I am new to programming and I am trying to figure out this problem. I have a list of elements and I want to find words that have the same length. This is what I've tried:

```
list1 = ["dog","cat","people","tank","pop","joop","count"]    
list3 = []

for i in range(len(list1)):   
    for j in range(len(list1):    
        if len(list1[i]) == len(list1[j]):    
            list3.append(list[i])
return list3
```

I want to return `list3 = [ "dog","cat","joop","tank"]` because each word in this last has the same length as at least one other word in the list.

Comment: What if you have two 3-letter words and two 4-letter words. They each match the other word in the pair, but not the other 2 words.

Comment: because when  `i == j` your are checking every word against itself.

Comment: How should it even be returned, a list? and as @Barmar said what if there is two length that are repeated?

Comment: @CoolGuy I want to return a  list with with the following list3 = ["dog,"cat"] since they are same length if I had a list that had list1 = ["bat","cat","dog"] I would return a list that contained "bat" "cat" and "dog"

Comment: @CoolGuy They seem to be talking about collecting them into `list3`

Comment: is this how it should be `['dog, dog', 'cat, dog', 'dog, cat', 'cat, cat', 'people, people', 'tank, tank']`? Please create a example list of how it should look like.

Comment: It's better to show some more inputs - with 3- and 4-letter words matching.

Comment: as Julian noted, you need to not compare lengths when i == j.   and as Barmar noted, you can have multiple groups of words of the same length.  You could create a dictionary , rather than a list which would hold a list for each length match you get.

Comment: Why shouldn't the output have `pop` in it? Isn't that the same length as `dog` and `cat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice for situations like this is to use a map rather than using a list:

```
list1 = ["dog","cat","people","tank","pop","joop","count"]     
results = {}
for item in list1:
    length = len(item)
    if length in results:
        results[length].append(item)
    else:
        results[length] = [item]

print(results) # {3: ['dog', 'cat', 'pop'], 6: ['people'], 4: ['tank', 'joop'], 5: ['count']}
```

This works by iterating over all words in `list1`, getting the number of characters in each and adding it to the dictionary entry associated with that length. You can then filter that dictionary for entries that contain more than one word:

```
import itertools
filtered = list(itertools.chain(*filter(lambda v: len(v) > 1, results.values())))
print(filtered) # ['dog', 'cat', 'pop', 'tank', 'joop']
```

This code works by calling the `filter` function with a lambda that checks if the value associated with each key (length) has more than one value, and then chaining these sub-lists together into a single list, which is returned. For more information on how `itertools.chain` works and why I included the `*`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists/953097#953097).

Answer (score 0):

If *we* understand your question by now, you do want to *group* all same-size words?  IF so, then you could try this *defaultdict* from **collections** module:

If this is not what you expect, then please make the *goal* clear.

```py
L = ['dog', 'cat', 'bike', 'book', 'packet']

from collections import defaultdict

ddc = defaultdict(list)

for item in L:
    size = len(item)          # find the size of each word
    ddc[size].append(item)    # then group them together by size

    
print(ddc)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {3: ['dog', 'cat'], 4: ['bike', 'book'], 6: ['packet']})
```

Comment: I want to return a list with the values ["dog","cat","bike","book"]. The reason I need a list is because I have to do additional manipulation once I find words of the same length

Comment: IT's very easy to make this dict to the list.   Can you try first at least? and come back with question.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to do something like this:

```
def find_multiples(words):
  lengths = [len(word) for word in words]
  multiples = [word for word in words if lengths.count(len(word)) > 1]
  return multiples
```

After doing some testing on this, the average time for running this function 10 times was 1.629 seconds, if speed is something you would like, and it is fairly compact.

Answer (score -1):

If it is possible the same word appears multiple times, you might choose this solution:

```
def tryit():
    list1 = ["dog","cat","people","tank","pop","joop","count"]    
    mydict = {}
    l = len(list1)
    for i in range(l):
        vi = list1[i]
        li = len(vi)
        for j in range(l):
            vj=list1[j]
            lj = len(vj)   
            if li == lj and i != j :
                if li in mydict:
                    additem(mydict[li],vi)
                    additem(mydict[li],vj)
                else:        
                    mydict[li] = [vi,vj]
    return mydict

def additem(list,v):
    if v in list:
        return # don't place duplicates in list
    else:
        list.append(v)
    # This depends on the fact that list is mutable, so 
    # the passed list is updated. 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(tryit())    enter code here
```

Result:
{3: ['dog', 'cat', 'pop'], 4: ['tank', 'joop']}